# Why is this function returning illogical results?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, math, rest

This is my function, it simply calculates a rating.

```
const calc = (Rating1, Review1,Rating2, Review2) => {
  return (Rating1 * Math.round(Review1) + Rating2 * Math.round(Review2)) / Math.round(Review2+Review1);
}
```

Here is the 1st `UseEffect` where I fetch data from an API and set it to states.

```
//UseEffect 1 
    useEffect(()=>{
           //API 1
            fetch(URL1)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                setData1(data);
            })
            
            //API 2
            fetch(URL2)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                setData2(data);
            })
    },[]);
```

Here is the 2nd `UseEffect` where I use my function

```
useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(calc(data1.rating,data1.total_reviews,data2.rating,data2.total_reviews))},[data1,data2])
```

For example: if the API returns:

**Rating1:**  3.2

**Rating2:**  4

**Review1:**  592

**Review2:**  95715

> **The result is** : 0.0052053677065872295

Comment: I suspect this is just operator precedence biting you: `a + b / c` means `a + (b / c)`. If you wanted `(a + b) / c` then write it that way with the explicit parentheses.

Comment: Not sure how that code actually runs. There is a syntax error in the `calc`

Comment: Firstly, fix the syntax error with your `calc` function, then also include the expected result in your question

Comment: Also your second `useEffect` needs a dependency list `[data1, data2]` so that it only runs when those variables change

Comment: Sorry, I made mistakes while typing the question. I modified it now.

Comment: Well I just ran your function with the given input, and I don't get those same results. I get `3.9950823927648043`

Comment: Like I said in my previous [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68642641/why-is-this-function-returning-illogical-results#comment121310802_68642641), you are likely using null values in your calculation, and JS is just trying to give you any answer. You need to make sure your `useEffect` is running only when `data1` and `data2` are defined, and you should check for this inside the callback

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I found the problem. The reviews I got from the API were strings. So the sum of `Review1 + Review2` (Review1: 592, Review2: 95715) is 59295715.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are potentially dealing with strings as arguments you should change your function to

```
const calc = (Rating1, Review1,Rating2,Review2) => {
  return (Rating1 * Review1 + Rating2 * Review2) /(+Review2+ +Review1);
}
```

The `Math.round()` operations in your original version are superfluous as the values were already integers in the first place.